# Is it safe to delete rows from Android SQLite database while iterating cursor

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cursor

For example:

```
public void removeStaleMovies(Set<String> updatedMovieList) {
    Cursor cur = this.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT id, title, year FROM movie", null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    while (!cur.isAfterLast()) {
        String title = cur.getString(1);
        String year = cur.getString(2);
        if (!updatedMovieList.contains(title + "-" + year)) {
              // delete the row where 'id' = cur.getString(0)
              // OR, delete the row using the object at the cursor's current position, if that's possible
              // OR, if deletion isn't safe while iterating, build up a list of row id's and run a DELETE statement after iteration is finished    
        }

    }
}
```

Is deletion safe to do? Or can it result in some unpredictable behavior? I am aware of [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929103/delete-current-row-in-sqlite3-while-iterating-over-a-result-set), but I'm still unsure.

Comment: i think you are trying to delete movies by id? or? which movies are you trying to delete?

Comment: Any movies that ARE in the database that are NOT in the supplied HashSet should be deleted

Comment: Yes it is safe. But is preferable if you can do a Delete statement to deleted that rows at once

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From a code safety standpoint, this should be OK, assuming that the result set of your query is less than 1MB. In that case, the `Cursor` holds in heap space the entire result set, so it is insulated from any changes to the underlying database.

That being said, you may want to build up a list of rows to delete, simply so you can delete them in a single statement, rather than a bunch of individual statements (though wrapping those individual statements in a transaction may give you similar performance characteristics).